# How do I create a string representation of a polynomial with complex co-efficients?

Tags: java

For example: (1.0+1.0i)+(1.0+2.0i)X+(1.0+3.0i)X^2

So far I have this,

```
public String toString() {

    for (int i = this.degree(); i >= 0; i--) {
        String result = (i + "x^" + i + " ");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Will this work for the example above?

Comment: javascript with types?

Comment: If you just want to build a polynomial string, you're on the right track.  Do you plan to actually evaluate this string at some point?

Comment: Is there anything else I need to add? And yes I will be evaluating it

Comment: public Complex evaluate(Complex z) {
     int p = 0;
        for (int i = degree(); i >= 0; i--)
            p = coeff[i] + (z * p);
        return p;
    }